# Using Xcode with Open GL

Tags: xcode, cmake

http://youtu.be/cKA6FQ6p4Mg

I've followed all the steps in the above tutorial including the Cmake part, but at 3:14 I archive as instructed and get the following error:

```
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: system error: no such file or directory
```

I tried running the Cmake project file from the terminal, entering my password, but this just resulted in more errors

Cheers, any help would be appreciated

Edward

Comment: I use OpenGL a lot, and I've never used this library.  It's not really necessary.  What are you trying to do with OpenGL?

Comment: Hi, at the moment I'm trying to just get started in open gl; i'm currently in the Window and OpenGL context creation stage. After, my first objective is: simulate a real world camera utilising the meta data of a photograph e.g focal etc. I've been reading a getting started guide and it recommended the GLFW library Thanks

Comment: IB will create a main window for you, and it's easy enough in IB to place an NSOpenGLView in that window.

Comment: hi jwlaughton, excuse my ignorance but what does IB stand for?

Comment: Interface Builder. If you have even the simplest Xcode project with a window, it will have already created a window for you named MainMenu.xib.  If you click on that file, it will take you into Interface Builder.

Comment: Great an interface is just what a visual person like my self who is new to code needs. In the picture i posted below - commenting on your longer answer - am i at the "with a window" stage?

Comment: That photo sort of looks a little like Xcode, but it doesn't look like an Xcode project.  I don't even see the Xcode menu bar at the top of the window.Try this.  Close that down for the moment.  Start Xcode and select (from the main menu) File -> New -> Project.  Select OS X Application.

Comment: Name it whatever you want.  Don't worry about the Organization Name, Organization Identifier or the Bundle Identifier.  Select Objective C as the language.  Be sure none of the check boxes are selected. Then Click the "Next" button.

Comment: Choose where you want to store the Project, then click the "Create" button.  You'll get a project opened and along the left side you'll see "MainMenu.xib.  Click on that file.  When you do you'll go into IB.

Comment: that sounds good, can I incorporate what ive done in to the workflow you've suggested? I believe It is a x code project "GLFW.xcodeproj" made it using Cmake & its a single file that when double clicked, opens in xcode

Comment: I've added a picture of this in my post.

Comment: I've also added a picture of the lower right corner of IB where I've typed "open" in the search window to show and OpenGLView Object.  You can drag this object into your window and re-size it as you want.

Comment: Does your project have a MainMenu.xib?

Comment: Ive been using the command line tool as a template - so no i dont have a .xib file; I guess that means we've been talking cross purposes. However I had a play around workflow you suggested, and it does seem a more intuitive way to do things especially in 3d. so I will look for opengl xcode tutorials

Comment: Also, check out the "Migrating to OpenGL Core Profile" video at https://developer.apple.com/opengl/. You may not understand everything that's going on, but you should be able to get an idea from watching this which tutorials are teaching you old technology verses new. There are lots of tutorials out there that teach methods no longer supported by Apple.

Comment: I saw in your GLEW project picture BTW that it was already giving you a deprication (old technology that will not continue to be supported at some point) warning.

Comment: So what exactly is depreciated; the glfw library?

Comment: No, not the whole library.  It looks like they are using one depricated method call "CGDisplayIOServicePort in their file cocoa_monitor.m.

Comment: Cheers, how do I t h a n k you on stack overflow; I'm new to this!

Comment: Accept the answer.  Did you check out that Apple site? There's actually lots of good stuff for you there.

Comment: yes cheers, im reading the “OpenGL on the Mac Platform”

Comment: Just to give you some perspective (because the OpenGL Core Profile involves a bit of work), I wrote an app for a company about a year ago that showed a spherical raised version of their logo pasted on an extruded spherical frame (with a custom texture background) pasted on a spherical ring that (in animation) circled a texture mapped globe (with an actual world map that included clouds and different reflectances for land and water i.e oceans and lakes with night lights turning on and off as appropriate)

Comment: I set my animation timer to fire 60 times/sec, but with OpenGL fixed functions I was only getting 10 buffer flushes(redraws)/sec which gave a very jerky animation.

Comment: Using the OpenGL Core Profile methods I at least got my buffer flushes up to 40/sec, which gave an acceptably smooth animation.

Comment: How can you differentiate between core and fixed? ;I've gt the latest OS X and my libraries are all up to date. That sounds like a very exciting project, got a pic? My first task is to look through the lens of a real world camera and match its lat long co-ordinates

Comment: I actually supplied the customer a .mov version of the output of that project. I'd be happy to give you the .mov (~100MB) (which includes shadowing), but the actual code involves many textures that I did not import into the Copy Bundle Resources.  My bad. They are referenced in the code as absolute  path names.

Comment: I've added an image of the starting point of that application animation.  The shadows will grow/appear as appropriate and the night lights will turn on as appropriate.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why u did it through code - very impressive - did u not have the flexibility u wanted in 3dsmax or something. I come from from that background; well Artlantis actually : http://www.crystallise3d.co.uk/motion.html. Would b great to see ur mov

Comment: You don't have enough points to move this to a chat. Maybe we should discuss this via email.  I don't see your email address in your profile, but you should be able to see mine: jwlaughton@aol.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment, so I'll post it here.

If you're just getting started and want to do "something", create a class (maybe call it MyOpenGLView) that is a subclass of NSOpenGLView.

Assuming you've put an NSOpenGLView view in your main window in IB, change the class of that view to MyOpenGLView and don't forget to select a depth buffer and check Double Buffer.

In you class, MyOpenGLView, you'll want to at least implement awakeFromNib (assuming you're using IB), prepareOpenGL and drawRect methods.  If you want, I'll post some code about those methods.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Jwlaugton, im sure that info will come in handy, but att the moment i've got the aformentioned error & dont know what to do about it. I cant post pictures yet but here is a link to one:http://i1303.photobucket.com/albums/ag156/eskimo___/screenshot_113_zpsf7f9444a.jpg cheers